# How do I use libsvm in Python without modifying sys.path?

Tags: python, libsvm

I installed libsvm in Ubuntu. All I want to do is call `from svmutil import *` in Python without it giving me an error. However, I see no good documentation on how to configure libsvm to work with python. "Adding libsvm to a path" tells me nothing.

And I don't want to use a package manager. What do I need to do to make libsvm found when running python outside of the original libsvm install folder?

```
(ykp) yannik@yannik-Inspiron-7580:~/Projects/libsvm$ ls
COPYRIGHT        java          python   svm.o          svm-toy
description-pak  libsvm.so.2   README   svm-predict    svm-train
doc-pak          Makefile      svm.cpp  svm-predict.c  svm-train.c
FAQ.html         Makefile.win  svm.def  svm-scale      tools
heart_scale      matlab        svm.h    svm-scale.c    windows
(ykp) yannik@yannik-Inspiron-7580:~/Projects/libsvm$ ls python
commonutil.py    Makefile     README  svmutil.py
description-pak  __pycache__  svm.py
```

I tried doing `sudo ln -s libsvm.so.2 /usr/local/lib` and adding `~/Projects/libsvm` to my `PYTHONPATH` with no success. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If `~/Projects/libsvm/python/` is where the module you want to import exists, then you have to add `~/Projects/libsvm/python/` to your PYTHONPATH not `~/Projects/libsvm/`. The PYTHONPATH doesn't just automatically recursively search down for python files if that is what you were expecting.